# Pilot light going out on my furnace

Tags: furnace

So I replace the thermocouple on my furnace a few weeks ago and it wasn’t the correct thermocouple the only difference was the housing so I figured I’d use it but what happened was the flame from the pilot only reached the very top quarter inch of the thermocouple.

Fast forward 2 to 3 weeks. I am having problems with my pilot going out. I noticed that my blower housing door was off, and wanted to know if that might’ve been the cause, maybe an excess airflow caused the flame to go out, but I really can’t see that being the case.

The only other thing that I can think of would be the thermocouple not being high enough to absorb most of the flames heat. Since it’s not the right thermocouple, I was going to see if I could takeoff the bracket that slides over the thermocouple that holds it onto the housing then I would just leave the thermocouple hang at a certain height without being attached to the housing since, the copper wire that the thermocouple is attached to would give it enough stability. If I weren’t to do this, I would have to get a whole new thermocouple and/or replace the housing.

Comment: Edited for format and thermal coupling >> thermocouple.

Comment: New thermocouple will cost you $10